# Smart contracts, tokens and ether

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, ether, erc-20

I am sending some ethers and tokens to my smart contract. So how will the contract differentiate between ethers and tokens?
Code will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

One is protocol and one is an app. You explicitly write the procedure for both cases.

**Ether**

The EVM uses ether to financially incentivize securing the network and verifying transactions. All ether originate with a found block and a reward paid to the miner that found it.

In a contract, `msg.value` is the amount of ether sent to a function, and the function must be marked `payable` or the transaction will revert.

Example:

```
function payMe() public payable {
  uint weGot = msg.value;
  // carry on
}
```

**Tokens**

A token is defined in a contract written in Solidity. Token contracts are simple ledgers with functions that attend to transactions and accounting.

Your contract *will not know* if someone "sends it" tokens because that is modelled as an adjustment to the token contract's ledger. Roughly, if Alice sends Bob 10 tokens:

```
balance[Alice] -= 10 tokens
balance[Bob] += 10 tokens
```

An actual ERC20 contract has more going on, but that is the effect. It is invoked by Alice signing a transaction to the contract, with the message,

`token.transfer(Bob, 10);`

Of course, contracts want to know if they have received ether, but they can't monitor every token contract that exists. The Approve/transferFrom flow solves this problem.

Alice will send a transaction to the token contract, approve(yourContract, 10r).

*In your contract*, you assume this was done (the UI should coordinate both steps), and then:

`token.transferFrom(Alice, address(this), 10);`

If Alice had previously approved it, it will succeed. Your contract knows it received tokens because it asked for them explicitly.

Hope it helps.